# Why is the Uninstall method not being called during installation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer

I am aware that there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667261/why-is-my-uninstall-method-not-called-from-the-msi) questions that are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052631/why-is-my-uninstall-method-not-being-called) but either they are not answered properly or the answer isn't fixing my problem.

My program has a main framework as well as various plugins for the framework. The plugins are managed via an XML file which contains the information needed by the framework to dynamically load the plugin.

I have a common `Installer` class which is used to handle the custom actions during installation for the Plugins.

During installation it needs to load the XML file and add a new node in it listing the information needed to load the plugin.

During uninstallation it just needs to remove that same node from the XML file.

Installation is working fine. When I attempt to uninstall the Plugin, the `Installer`'s Uninstall method doesn't even get called.

If any more information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem, that the uninstall method did not get executed.
After I uninstalled the setup and all files in the target location, I removed all references in the registry with the setup name and primary output file name. (Except those key values used by visual studio)
After that, the uninstall method was executing again.
It looks like previous unsuccessful installations where not cleaned up well in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the uninstall custom action save the project and then add it back again. Also, if you want to debug the setup package, you can add the following:

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

At the beggining of the overriden method instead of using message boxes.

Comment: Tried removing it and adding it again (a couple times in fact). I didn't know about `Debugger.Launch()` but when adding it to the beginning of the 4 different types of custom actions, only the ones for `Install` and `Commit` are launching the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the Custom Action is configured properly? I'd recommend you put in some MessageBoxes all over the place so you can track what's happening.

Comment: That's how I know that the `Uninstall` method isn't being called. I have a MessageBox in each of the 4 actions so I can tell exactly when each one is being called. `Install` and `Commit` are being called, `Rollback` and `Uninstall` are not. I really don't care about `Rollback` at the moment, only `Uninstall`.

Comment: And you've confirmed that "InstallerClass" is "true" on that Custom Action and it points to the proper assembly?

Comment: Yes, for all four Custom Action types.

Comment: Is the DLL which houses the installer class still located in the installation directory at the time of the uninstall?

Comment: Yes. A problem I used to have was one plugin would remove it making the removal of another plugin afterwards fail. This was fixed by setting the `Installer`'s dll to be set to be Permanent via setting the corresponding property in the setup's File System configuration. (Do note however that I've tried leaving the Permanent to false (which is default) in a quick test to see if that was causing the `Uninstall` issue).

Comment: You didn't post any code so I'm assuming the installer methods are overridden properly. Other than that, I'm out of ideas. But I'll let you know if I think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/617415/10234)

I believe sometimes Visual Studio does an in place upgrade, and doesn't actually uninstall the old version.